# Sitecore Glass Mapper property from multiple fields

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I´m using Sitecore and Glass Mapper, and I´d like to know if the following is possible:

I have a Sitecore Item, which has 5 fields. These fields are CSS classes (height, width, effects, icons, etc). It´s a metro style webpage, so the idea is to allow the user to change some settings on the fly.

Instead of making 5 different properties, and access each field, I´d like to know if there is a way to return those 5 fields as a list, or a string.

```
public class CSSClass
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual Image Name { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "CSS Class")]
    public virtual string CSSClass { get; set; }
}
```

That would be my Model for each setting. 
And this is my Tile:

```
public class WelcomeTile
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CSSClass> CSSClasses { get; set; }
}
```

And I´d like to access those in the property CSSCLasses, instead of going one by one like this, for example:

```
[SitecoreField]
public virtual CSSClass Hieght { get; set; }
[SitecoreField]
public virtual CSSClass Icon { get; set; }
[SitecoreField]
public virtual CSSClass Width{ get; set; }
[SitecoreField]
public virtual CSSClass Effect { get; set; }
```

Comment: to clarify, your data item already has 5 fields on it, which represent 5 different categories of CSS classes, right? The part that I don't follow is the type `CSSClass`, I don't follow how the fields match up to the `CSSClass`; would you have instance objects of the `CSSClass` type for each of the fields? If so, why this level of encapsulation? What is the Image property in `CSSClass` used for? I think it may be easier to achieve what you want with what you have in the third code snippet, and augment that a bit. I'll expound on this in an answer after some clarification.

Comment: As CodeMonkey1313 says, the examples you have given do not make sense. Is `CSSClass` as Sitecore Data Template? How are you generating your Glass models, manually or using TDS?

Comment: Yes, CSSClasses are data templates in Sitecore.

Comment: Each CSSClasss has a title, and a name (the cssclass name I want to attach to each Tile).
Each Tile item, has a dropdown for each property, so the user can select them and change them quickly.
Is the third option better than using one property?
I´m new to Glass mapper, and I don´t have a lot of practice with it.
Also, modified the third code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments above that i am not sure about how you data structure is working. However any custom mapping of data can be achieved using a custom data handler, see this blog post:

http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19

Comment: Hi @Michael Edwards. Your link brings me to a 404 page. I figured out, that it should be http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial19, right?